# +this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id') showing error

Tags: angular

```
loadProduct() {
this.shopService.getProduct(+this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')).subscribe(product => {
  this.product = product;
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
});
}
```

In above code the product details showing and working fine but I am getting an error in vs code from line 2

```
+this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
```

Now what can I do please?

> Error: src/app/shop/product-details/product-details.component.ts:21:34 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'. 21 this.shopService.getProduct(+this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')).subscribe(product => { ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ –

Comment: Which error is it showing ?!

Comment: Error: src/app/shop/product-details/product-details.component.ts:21:34 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

    21     this.shopService.getProduct(+this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')).subscribe(product => {
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just I have to change a little bit to fix it-
my previous code is

```
+this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
```

and my correction code is-

```
+this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id']
```

This code is working fine

Answer (score 0):

The `paramMap` may not contain an `'id'` key. The return type of `get` method is actually `string | null`.

And when doing `+...paramMap.get('id')` you are potentially doing `+null`, which is why this error appears.

Comment: export interface IProduct {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
  pictureUrl: string;
  productType: string;
  productBrand: string;
}  This is my IProduct Interface